# node socket io - sharing a global object across sockets and between client and server

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In socket.io, for node.js, is there a way to exchange a global object between client and server by assigning the object to socket? Or do i have to create a emit event to exchange the global object.

In my case, the global object is a array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to emit it.

However, the resulting object will not maintain state between the client and server.  When you emit it, it is serialized, send over the wire, and re-created on the other end.  If you were to later add data to that object on the server, the client would not see that new data (nor vice versa).

You can use something like [Racer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/racer) to handle this for you.